# ActionScript 3 framework / engine for building social game like FarmVille

Tags: actionscript-3, isometric, social-gaming

The current architecture of the game is:

- PHP + MySql backend,
- Flash and ActionScript 3 frontend.

Major criteria for engine/framework selection are:

1. Support for isometric view.
2. Resuability : The current game development should easy the work for building similar social game of diffrent story type in future.
3. Ease of development

Already researched stuff:

1. as3isolib - for isometric rendering, but restricted only to the rendering part.
2. PushButton Engine - open source engine, component based
3. Open-space engine - But That works with Smart Fox Server only I guess.

Any other good recommendations ?

Comment: Please mark answers which are useful with an upvote (when you can) and apply thee check to the most useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not suggesting any particular engine. The choice depends on a number of factors like number of people in the team, target time period, expected number of users, budget etc. etc. But you should check [this list of flash game engines](http://www.flashrealtime.com/flash-game-library-engine-list/). And also check [this list of flash isometric engines](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/02/23/11-flash-isometric-engines-you-can-use-in-your-games/).

Answer (score 2):

There's a comprehensive list of libraries at http://fluxdb.fluxusproject.org

- http://fluxdb.fluxusproject.org/libraries/4-as3isolib
- http://fluxdb.fluxusproject.org/libraries/210-ffilmation

Are both isometric libraries.